# Android Twitter4J set listview data force closes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, twitter4j

I am using `Twitter4J` library in my app. I get the `twitter` feeds and I want to set them to a `listview`. If I use `statuses.size()` to get their amount, It is successful, I get 20 feeds printed. But if I want to set the data to `listview` it force closes.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<Status> statuses = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView i = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        final ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxxx")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxxxxxx");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    try {
        String user;
        user = "xxxxxxx";
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
        Log.i("Status Count", statuses.size() + " Feeds");
        statuses.toArray();
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }

        }
    }).start();


        }
    }
```

Now the app works, A `layout` appears blank (cuz I didn't insert data to the `listview`, and I get `11-10 14:53:46.269: I/Status Count(16935): 20 Feeds` which means the .size worked.)

```
i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Status>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statuses));
```

But if I add this after the `}).start();` there is no error in `eclipse`, but the app force closes in the phone.

the **`logcat`**:

```
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at xxxxxxxxxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
11-10 14:55:39.749: E/AndroidRuntime(18153):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: May be you haven't initialized your statues list object

Comment: you have just declared it on the top......

Comment: something like...... Button b; as a global variable and after that on create method initialize with b = new Button();

Comment: I did,     List<Status> statuses;
 same error